# How to transfer domain registered through Blogger to a new registrar?

Tags: domains, blogger, domain-registrar

I'm preparing a client for migrating his Blogger blog to a self-hosting WordPress site. The client is currently running his Blogger blog using a custom domain name which he registered  through Blogger. Now that he wants to move to a self-hosted `wordpress.org` site, how can we transfer ownership of his domain name from Blogger to another registrar? Or, is this even necessary? I mean, can you set your Blogger domains' nameservers just like you can with any other domain registrar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blogger is not a registrar. When your client signed up, he or she should have received an e-mail from Google Apps detailing whether the domain was registered through eNom or GoDaddy (the registrar partners used for domain registrations).

If your client does not have his or her domain purchase confirmation e-mail, the DNS settings may be completed by observing the following process:

1. [Log in to Google Apps](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=55647) using Blogger domain name, username, and password
2. Go to *Domain Settings* > *Domain Names* > *Advanced DNS Settings* to find the eNom/GoDaddy account information for the domain
3. Log in at [eNom](https://www.enom.com/login.aspx?) or [GoDaddy](http://www.godaddy.com/default.aspx) to complete any desired changes

Not tested: Instructions culled from [Blogger Help](http://www.google.com/support/blogger/bin/static.py?page=ts.cs&ts=1233381) and [The Blog Doctor](http://www.blogdoctor.me/2008/12/how-to-change-dns-settings-for-custom.html) (oddly enough, this process does not appear to be described in detail at the Blogger Help site).

Comment: Cool, thanks for the information! I've never worked with custom domains with Blogger and I figured they used a proper registrar and not "themselves". Thanks for the DNS settings tips, too. I'm not too surprised that the process isn't detailed at the Blogger help site -- clearly they want people to stay with (the newly updated) Blogger platform rather than move to WordPress or whatever!

Answer (score 0):

Yes Google application only helps you to manage your domain, they will even make you understand that Google does not register a domain themselves. They work with either eNom or GoDaddy.